# Reduce execution time of a code that uses binary search

Tags: c, binary-search, execution-time

The problem is to create an array of player ranks based on 2 other arrays: leaderboard and player scores.  More explanations of the problem here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem.

The code below is a spaghetti but it's working fine. But, for large size of ranked array(200000 elements for example), it times out. I'm not asking for code to copy/paste. I just wanna know if there is a way to optimize this code.

```
int* climbingLeaderboard(int ranked_count, int* ranked, int player_count, int* player, int* result_count) {
    
    *result_count=player_count;
    // remove duplicates
    int removed=0;
    for(int i=0, j=1; i<ranked_count-removed; i++, j++){   
      if(ranked[i]==ranked[j]){
        for(int k=j; k<ranked_count-removed; k++) 
           ranked[k]=ranked[k+1]; 
        removed++;
      }
    }
    int newsize=ranked_count-removed;
    // create an array to store ranks then fill it
    int* positions=malloc(newsize*sizeof(int));
    positions[0]=1;
    for(int i=0, j=1; j<newsize; i++, j++){
        positions[j]=(ranked[j]<ranked[i])? (positions[i]+1) : positions[i];
    }
    // create and fill the results array using binary search
    int* res = malloc(player_count*sizeof(int));
    int start=0, end=newsize-1, middle=(start+end)/2;
    int j, k=newsize-1;
    for(int i=0; i<player_count; i++){
        if(i>0&&player[i]==player[i-1]){
            *(res+i)=(*(res+(i-1))); 
            continue;
        }
        if(player[i]>=ranked[middle]){
            *(res+i)=positions[middle]; 
            j=middle-1;
            while(j>=0){
                if(player[i]>=ranked[j]) 
                    *(res+i)=positions[j];
                else if(j==k) 
                    *(res+i)=positions[j]+1; 
                else break; 
                --j;
            }
            start=0; end=middle-1;
        }
        else{
            *(res+i)=positions[newsize-1]+1; 
            j=newsize-1;
            while(j>=middle){
                if(player[i]>=ranked[j]) 
                    *(res+i)=positions[j];
                else if(j==k) 
                    *(res+i)=positions[j]+1; 
                else break; 
                --j;
            }
            start=middle+1; end=newsize-1;
        }
        middle=(start+end)/2;
    }
    free(positions);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The "efficient algorithm" is just as much a *part* of these problems as the actual coding. Maybe more so, because you need to be able to code anyway.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `*(res+i)`. This is equivalent to `res[i]` and the latter is generally considered easier to read and understand.

Comment: The enter key is your friend. It will be easier for you to follow the flow of your own code (and find problems with it) if you don’t put as much as possible on single lines. If you put braces on their own lines and a newline after every semicolon your code will be significantly more readable.

Comment: I'm not going to create an account on HackerRank to read the description of the problem you're trying to sole and the constraints on the input. That belongs in the question here.

Comment: @RetiredNinja you don't need an account to read the problem. Just close the popup.

Comment: @WeatherVane Perhaps that works, but all of the information needed to answer the question should be part of the question. That page could move or be removed in the future.

Comment: Can you reformat the code for readability? As posted, it is artificially difficult to optimize.

Comment: @44stonelions I see that writing the maximum of instructions in one line is better than scrolling. Anyways, I always look for code readability after solving the problem :)

Comment: @redone_lsf But if no one can read your code, no one can help you.

Comment: @redone_lsf: I would advise you to change this approach: readable code helps solve the problem. Cramming statements on the same line causes hard to find bugs. The space bar is your friend

Comment: @redone_lsf: more horizontal space needed. Get rid of the `*(res+i)` syntax and avoid multiple statements on the same line...

Comment: @chqrlie I think it is readable now

Comment: @redone_lsf: I'm afraid I don't, sorry I cannot help you more.

Comment: *fill the results array using binary search*: there seems to be a lot of linear searches in this loop.

Comment: @chqrlie I was trying to solve the problem the fastest possible way

Comment: modifying the argument arrays should not be allowed...

Comment: @WeatherVane when the final `else` is not executed. `--j;` will be executed

Comment: @chqrlie I modified the array because it won't be used elsewhere in the program.

Comment: It was the one-line code that caused confusion. It's more readable now.

Comment: @redone_lsf: indeed given how `main` is written, it won't, but it is an unnecessary side effect of your function `climbingLeaderboard`. Such side effects are nasty in production code.

Comment: This is a [multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap), which you can implement in C as a tree.

Comment: @redone_lsf *I always look for code readability after solving the problem*  That won't work so well when you're trying to solve **real** problems that take days or weeks to work on instead of some toy.  When you come back to code you wrote two weeks ago, **you** won't be able to read it.

Answer (score 1):

The initial loop to remove duplicates has a potential quadratic time complexity. You can achieve linear complexity using the 2 finger approach:

```
    int removed = 0;
    for (int i = 1, j = 1; j < ranked_count; j++) {
        if (ranked[i - 1] != ranked[j])
            ranked[i++] = ranked[j];
        else
            removed++;
    }
```

More generally, the argument arrays should not be changed in spite of the sloppy prototype given:

```
int *climbingLeaderboard(int ranked_count, int *ranked,
                         int player_count, int *player,
                         int *result_count);
```

Here are simple steps I would recommend to solve this problem:

- allocate and initialize a `ranking` array with the ranking for each of the scores in the `ranked` array. Be careful to allocate `ranked_count + 1` elements.
- allocate a result array `res` of length `player_count`, set the `result_count` to `player_count`.
- starting with `pos = ranked_count`, for each entry `i` in `player`:

  - locate the position `pos` where the entry would be inserted in the `ranking` array using binary search between position `0` and the current `pos` inclusive. Make sure you find the smallest entry in case of duplicate scores.
  - set `res[i]` to `ranking[pos]`
- free the `ranking` array
- return the `res` array.

Here is a simple implementation:

> `int *climbingLeaderboard(int ranked_count, int *ranked,`
>                           `int player_count, int *player,`
>                           `int *result_count)`
>  `{`
>      `if (player_count <= 0) {`
>          `*result_count = 0;`
>          `return NULL;`
>      `}`
>      `int *ranking = malloc(sizeof(*ranking) * (ranked_count + 1));`
>      `int rank = 1;`
>      `ranking[0] = rank;`
>      `for (int i = 1; i < ranked_count; i++) {`
>          `if (ranked[i] != ranked[i - 1])`
>              `rank++;`
>          `ranking[i] = rank;`
>      `}`
>      `ranking[ranked_count] = rank + 1;`
>   
>      `int *res = malloc(sizeof(*res) * player_count);`
>      `*result_count = player_count;`
>   
>      `int pos = ranked_count;`
>      `for (int i = 0; i < player_count; i++) {`
>          `int start = 0;`
>          `while (start < pos) {`
>              `int middle = start + (pos - start) / 2;`
>              `if (ranked[middle] > player[i])`
>                  `start = middle + 1;`
>              `else`
>                  `pos = middle;`
>          `}`
>          `res[i] = ranking[pos];`
>      `}`
>      `free(ranking);`
>      `return res;`
>  `}`

Comment: I will try these steps

Answer (score 0):

Look for ways to use "branchless" to improve execution speed:

```
    positions[0]=1;
    for(int i=0, j=1; j<newsize; i++, j++){
        positions[j]=(ranked[j]<ranked[i])? (positions[i]+1) : positions[i];
    }
```

becomes

```
    positions[0] = 1;
    for( int i = 0, j = 1; j < newsize; i++, j++ )
        positions[j] = positions[i] + (ranked[j] < ranked[i]);
```

Other than this, I don't even want to try to sort out what this code is attempting.